# Drupal text module multiline widget for varchar field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Correct me if I'm wrong, but varchar in database is better for performance if you have multiple fields per node. Now if I select multiline text - I automaticaly get text field in database which is what I don't want.

To get multiline in text fields I could hack text.module and get what I want with one additional word like this:

Instead of:

`function text_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
...
    'text_textarea' => array(
...
      'field types' => array('text_long'),
...
    ),
...`

change to:

`function text_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
...
    'text_textarea' => array(
...
      'field types' => array('text_long', 'text'),
...
    ),
...`

Changing core modules of course is not good.
Is there any elegant way to hook and extend text module in my own module without rewriting the widget - can I tell to allow textarea not only text_long, but also text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement hook_field_widget_info_alter() to change the type. Don't forget to clear the cache for the changes to be visible.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I did it like this: `function arcustommodule_field_widget_info_alter(&$info) {
    $info ['text_textarea']['field types'][] = 'text';
}`

Answer (score 1):

There's also [a module for Text area widget for text fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/textarea_widget_for_text) now which implements [hook_field_widget_info_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info_alter/8) exactly as shown in Aurimas Rekštys' comment to Web-Beest's answer.  This is useful for anyone who wishes to install a contributed module rather than creating or adding to their own custom module.